# Selenium C# - Selecting an element from a dynamic menu which doesn't exist until hover over

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am using Selenium IDE in Firefox to perform a series of tests. They work fine in the Firefox IDE but when I export the test cases as C# / NUnit / WebDriver I am coming across a few changes I have to made to the C# code before it works. I am running the tests using NUnit.

In this case, I am trying to select a link from a dynamic menu which doesn't exist until you hover over the dynamic menu with your mouse. I have tried to get Selenium C# to start a hover over command and then a sleep command to give the menu time to load but I am not having much luck. I am running the code the website in a Firefox browser and using NUnit to run my tests.

When I export the below test case as C#, it fails as it cannot find the sublink from the dynamic menu. I have got other links to work that are visible on the page.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

This is my working Selenium IDE code:

```
  <title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>(Website link here)</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>link=(Link that exists when you hover over the dynamic menu)</td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I export this test case as a C# / NUnit / WebDriver I get:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "(Website Link)");
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("(Link from the dynamic menu)")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try building an action for mouseover then click on element (instead of a simple click) after 1st mouseover. Otherwise, you can always use JavaScript to click such elements.

Comment: At least you could have provided a link to some additional information for the asker. So, I do: http://www.learnseleniumtesting.com/mouse-hover-and-other-mouse-events-in-webdriver/